# Replace fragment and recrate Activity will crash

Tags: android, android-fragments

My function is click FagmentOne ImageView,it will replace itself to FragmentTwo,

and click FragmentTwo textView will recrate Activity.

but recrate Activity will crash.

Why and how to fix it...?

this is Activity Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.testfunction.MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/fragmentBlock"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentBlock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        <fragment
            android:tag="fra"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.example.testfunction.FragmentOne"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

FragmentOne Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_switch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:onClick="go" />

</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentTwo Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Large Text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity Code:

```
private FragmentManager mManager;
    private Fragment two = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mManager = getFragmentManager();
    }

    public void go(View view){
        FragmentTransaction ft = mManager.beginTransaction();
        if(two == null){
            two = new FragmentTwo();
        }
        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentBlock, two,"fra");
        ft.commit();
    }
```

FragmentTwo code:

```
LinearLayout root = null;
    TextView status = null;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return root = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bar_status, container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if(status == null){
            status = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.textView_status);
            status.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getActivity().recreate();
    }
```

error message:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
    at com.example.testfunction.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    ... 10 more
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    ... 18 more
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.example.testfunction.FragmentOne did not create a view.
```

Thanks.

**Add**

FragmentOne code:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bar_layout, container,false);
    }

}
```

Comment: The exception said your FragmentOne didn't create a view. Can you post `onCreateView()` method of FragmentOne?

Comment: @ReyPham add it. thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494429/getting-fragment-did-not-create-a-view-after-adition-of-other-fragment-without)